# Do I need a custom JS player for HTML 5 Video even I'm only considering the devices which has default support for HTML 5 Video?

Tags: android, html, mobile-safari, mobile-website, html5-video

I'm Making a Mobile website using jquery mobile and I'm only considering iPad, iPhone and Android device. I don't need Flash Fallback.

Then what is the best method to make video player only for mobile? Do i have to use any of these http://praegnanz.de/html5video/ or only html 5 video code will do. I don't need custom skin. Main thing is video should be smoothly played on iPad, iphone and Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to use one of those video libraries; you can use the HTML5 video element which allows you to style the controls via CSS and specify fallbacks (including flash and silverlight).

The main thing to consider will be what video codecs each mobile browser on iphone, ipad and android supports.
In between the  tags, you can specify multiple video formats to fallback on.

I tested this on iphone and ipad and it could play the video using the HTML5 video element:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
      <source src="http://blip.tv/file/get/Qtv-CarrieFisherTalksStarWarsOnQ553.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

iOS will support mp4 but i'm not an Android expert so i found this post that details encoding video that will play on Android via the html5 video element: [Encoding Video For Android](http://www.broken-links.com/2010/07/30/encoding-video-for-android/)